# Relative path to sdcard stored mp3 files from app on MID tablet running android not working

Tags: android, android-sdcard

When I ran on View Pad7 used **sdcard/night1/9472012051_346.mp3** with success.

If I prompt for the root directory from within the app I get **/mnt/sdcard/**, however `Prompt(IsFileExist("/mnt/sdcard/night1/9472012051_346.mp3"));` returns false.

Explorer app on tablet shows path as **SD Card/night1/9472012051_346.mp3**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many tablets have their own internal memory, and this is what is mounted to /mnt/sdcard (which is symlinked to by /sdcard). In these cases, any external sdcard you install is typically at /mnt/external_sd instead